# Turning off antialiasing on zoom with quad in Löve2D

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm using [Löve2D](https://love2d.org/) for writing a small game. Löve2D is an open source game engine for Lua. The problem I'm encountering is that some antialias filter is automatically applied to your sprites when you draw it at **integer** positions.

```
love.graphics.draw( texture, quad, x, y, r, sx, sy)
```

My plan was :

1. Cut a small image into 9 to fit Quad.
2. Zoom in on it to fit the UI.
3. Make Variable UI.

My image was :
[full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYI1f.png)

Zoom in :
[5px green rectangle in 15px rounded rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4ZCw.png)

And My test code was :

```
function love.load()
    sprite = love.graphics.newImage('image.png')
    centerbox = love.graphics.newQuad(5, 5, 5, 5, sprite:getDimensions()
end
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(sprite, centerbox, 0, 0, 0, 30, 30)
```

I want display only that blue :
[x=5px, y=5px, w=5px, h=5px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81aRp.png)

Result :
[That's not fun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krdXE.png)
5 is **integer**, 30 is **integer**, 0 is **integer**.

My UI is :
[That's not cool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO6Yd.png)

How can I get only the pixels I want?
i've already read [Turning off antialiasing in Löve2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271937/turning-off-antialiasing-in-l%C3%B6ve2d).

Comment: Is it sufficient to just turn off the [filtering](https://love2d.org/wiki/Texture:setFilter)? Or do you need a filter, but without bleeding? In any case, if you use quads you should use a margin, as said in the link Koyaanisqatsi posted. Makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read...
https://love2d.org/wiki/Quad
...especially the yellow Alertbox.